# What edition of dnd should i use?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

I am a newer DM for Dungeons and dragons, recently created my own club and i need to get an edition but i don't know the large differences between them. I want to be able to craft a story that is very deep into fantasy but allows me to have large amount of freedom. I do not want to be to combat focused for while i do like combat it's definitely  not something i'm fully good at i'm batter at story and that.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Things work a little differently here than they do on other websites. I highly recommend you take the [tour](/tour). I'm afraid that this question, while important, is poorly suited to this site because any answer you get would be an opinion, which we try to avoid.

Comment: Welcome to the site (and, presumably, the hobby)! Take the [tour]. I know it's disappointing, but [the site can't handle shopping questions like this](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5747/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic-revisited). However, I am certain [many forums like these](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/8610) would be happy to help you in your search. When you've picked an edition—or [a different role-playing game entirely!](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1475/8610)—and have questions about it, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Despite the title, I think this is a dupe of [What are the big differences between the D&D editions?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/13212) or possibly  [How can I learn about other editions of D&D?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/36358)